# GWT Decorated Cell Table input rendered onclick

Tags: input, gwt, cell, edit

I have a `DecoratedCellTable` where I can do inline editing. 
But when I click on my `editbutton` nothing happens to the `CellTable`. Only when I click into the cell I want to edit, the cell is rendered as `<input>`.

Is there a way to render all editable cells as input by clicking on my `editbutton` ?

With `cellTable.setEditable(true);` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

See Cells are defined per Column not per entry in the column.

`The basic idea of cell widgets is to make the widget light wieght by not creating the input elements for each entry in the column`.

So there can be only one input element that can be active in a column at any point of time and same input element is reused for entire column.

Hence it is not possible (as per i know ) to render all editable cells as input
elements at a time.

Comment: In my opinion that could be tricky. Because you have to click on each element automatickly.

Comment: Exotic solution - You can use a simple form in a popup styled like a row and float it over the cell table row !!!!